# How to add unique ID to each row in my table

Tags: html

can I know how to add unique ID to each row in my table ,below is my HTML code.
The fields are just static cant insert any text apart from first table so I would like to create a unique ID for each row to enable adding the text.

```html
 <table id="layoutsTable" style="width&#58;100%;">
 <tbody>
 <tr style="vertical-align&#58;top;"><td colspan="3"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"><p>
  &#160;</p></div></div></td></tr><tr style="vertical-align&#58;top;"><td style="width&#58;33.3%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"><p>
   &#160;</p></div></div></td><td class="ms-wiki-columnSpacing" style="width&#58;33.3%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"></div>
    &#160;</div></td><td class="ms-wiki-columnSpacing" style="width&#58;33.3%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"></div>
    &#160;</div></td></tr><tr style="vertical-align&#58;top;"><td colspan="3"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"></div>
   &#160;</div></td></tr> </tbody></table>
                
            <table id="layoutsTable#" style="width&#58;100%;">
 <tbody>
 <tr style="vertical-align&#58;top;"><td style="width&#58;33.3%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"><p>
   &#160;</p></div></div></td><td class="ms-wiki-columnSpacing" style="width&#58;33.3%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"></div>
    &#160;</div></td><td class="ms-wiki-columnSpacing" style="width&#58;33.3%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"></div>
    &#160;</div></td></tr><tr style="vertical-align&#58;top;"><td colspan="3"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"></div>
   &#160;</div></td></tr> </tbody> 
            </table>
            
               <table id="layoutsTable" style="width&#58;100%;">
 <tbody>
 <tr style="vertical-align&#58;top;"><td style="width&#58;33.3%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"><p>
   &#160;</p></div></div></td><td class="ms-wiki-columnSpacing" style="width&#58;33.3%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"></div>
    &#160;</div></td><td class="ms-wiki-columnSpacing" style="width&#58;33.3%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"></div>
    &#160;</div></td></tr><tr style="vertical-align&#58;top;"><td colspan="3"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width&#58;100%;"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"></div>
   &#160;</div></td></tr> </tbody> 
            </table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add it static, just write differnet names on every row id's :

```
<tr id="layoutsRow1", 
<tr id="layoutsRow2", 
<tr id="layoutsRow3"
```

But your tables should have different ID's as well , I don't know exactly what is your goal , but this seems to work for you.

Comment: Hi ,I want to add unique ID to each table aswell as unique ID to each row inside the table,do I need to replace  <table id="layoutsTable" style="width&#58;100%;">     with <table id="layoutsRow1" style="width&#58;100%;">

Comment: Yes , because an HTML element can only have one unique id that belongs to that single element :)

Comment: when I replace my  <table id="layoutsTable" style="width&#58;100%;"> with <table id="layoutsRow1" style="width&#58;100%;"> I am unable to insert any text to the rows as my target is to enable the static rows able to insert some text .

Comment: You shouldn't replace tables id's , you should create brand new id's for all tables , sorry I 'miss in your previous comment word "replace" . You can have only one unique id per element, thats mean you can't reuse it like a class into other html elements. You should create diffrenet id's for other elements as well.

Comment: Hi ,can you able to provide with an example based on my above code?

Comment: Sure, check here : https://pastebin.com/z4pLH082 ... Must be something like this :)

Comment: When I amend the table ID and Row ids my first table and row itself become static and cant able to insert any text,before in my first table one header ,3 columns I managed to insert text after editing with creating new id to table and rows they become static.